# How to show data table in a box with background color in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to put my data table in a box in my shiny dashboard. I set my box background color as green. However, I found my data table content does not display in the box.  Does anyone know how to fix this issue? thanks.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "example"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        box(width=6, background = 'green',
            DT::dataTableOutput('table') 
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(iris)
    })
}    


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your code works for me (but the width of the box is too small).

Comment: I can only see the table content when I click on rows.  You did not see any issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a matter of your font color:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "example"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(width=6, background = 'green',
        DT::dataTableOutput('table') 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df <- iris
    DT::datatable(df) %>% 
      # rowid is a column as well, therefore zero to nrow()
      DT::formatStyle(0:nrow(df), color = "black")
  })
}    


shinyApp(ui, server)
```